# Python Error : TypeError: patientInfo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Disease'

Tags: python, oop

I'm brand new to Python, and I'm trying to learn how to work with classes. Does anyone know how come this is not working?
code  is here:

this is my patient class

```
class Patient:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, name, Age, Gender, Disease):
        self.name = name
        self.Age = Age
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Disease = Disease

    # Function to create and append new patient
    def patientInfo(self, Name, Age, Gender, Disease):
        # use  ' int(input()) ' method to take input from user
        ob = Patient(Name, Age, Gender, Disease)
        ls.append(ob)
```

and want to access `patientInfo` in main class but while accessing getting errors regarding the positional argument.

code of the main class is here:

```
                   elif user_choice == 2:
                    print()
                    f = open("myfile.txt", "a")
                    f.write(input('\n'))
                    # "{}\n".format(name)
                    name = f.write(input("Name: "+ "\n"))
                    f.write("\n")
                    Age = f.write((input("Age: "+ "\n")))
                    Gender = f.write(input("Gender: "+ "\n"))
                    Disease = f.write(input("Disease: "+ "\n"))
                    f.close()
                    Patient.patientInfo(name, Age, Gender, Disease)
```

can you please suggest to me where I am going wrong?

Comment: try to call like this bro `Patient().patientInfo(name, Age, Gender, Disease)`

Comment: why calling the parent class in same class method?

Comment: `patientInfo` needs to be decorated with [@classmethod decorator](https://pythonbasics.org/classmethod/) in order to be called without an instance of `Patient`. Because of that in your example one of the parameters is consumed by the `self` parameter, so the last one `Disease` is empty

Comment: also other aspects of your code wont work. You are wrapping `input()` into `f.write()` which means the value from `input()` will be written into the file, but `f.write()` does not return anything, so all your variables there will be empty.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko `f.write` return no of characters wriiten

Comment: ok my bad, but I'd assume that's not the value they expect in the variable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work, you have 2 options:

1. If you want to call `patientInfo` without creating an object of class `Patient` then change the function as below:

```
     @staticmethod
     def patientInfo(Name, Age, Gender, Disease):
        # use  ' int(input()) ' method to take input from user
        ob = Patient(Name, Age, Gender, Disease)
        ls.append(ob)
```

2. If you dont want to change the function declaration as above:
   Create an object (say `obj`) of class `Patient` and call it as `obj.patientInfo(...)`